# Transform the payload by grouping the fields in mule 4 dataweave

Tags: json, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

The below JSON Response containing collection which needs to be iterate and group according to the field `serviceType`.

**Response:**

```
{
    data:[
    {
            "jobCardNumber": "JC20026333",
            "serviceType": "RUNNING REPAIR",
            "partAmt": 1659.98,
            "labourAmt": 727.48,
            "totalAmt": 2387.46,
            "estPartAmt": 0.0,
            "estLabourAmt": 0.0,
            "estTotalAmt": 0.0,
            "partBasic": 1356.12,
            "partDiscount": null,
            "labourBasic": 616.5,
            "variant": "MARUTI WAGON R LXI BS4",
            "color": "SUPERIOR WHITE"
            },
            {
            "jobCardNumber": "JC20026456",
            "serviceType": "BODY REPAIR",
            "partAmt": 1659.98,
            "labourAmt": 727.48,
            "totalAmt": 2387.46,
            "estPartAmt": 0.0,
            "estLabourAmt": 0.0,
            "estTotalAmt": 0.0,
            "partBasic": 1356.12,
            "partDiscount": null,
            "labourBasic": 616.5,
            "variant": "MARUTI WAGON R LXI BS4",
            "color": "SUPERIOR WHITE"
            },
            {
            "jobCardNumber": "JC20026456",
            "serviceType": "RUNNING REPAIR",
            "partAmt": 1659.98,
            "labourAmt": 727.48,
            "totalAmt": 2387.46,
            "estPartAmt": 0.0,
            "estLabourAmt": 0.0,
            "estTotalAmt": 0.0,
            "partBasic": 1356.12,
            "partDiscount": null,
            "labourBasic": 616.5,
            "variant": "MARUTI WAGON R LXI BS4",
            "color": "SUPERIOR WHITE"
            }
            ]
        }
```

Each collection having field `serviceType`, I need to group and transform the data according to the type, meaning that, if service type is same then we need to group the related fields and create another collection of it called `history`.

The below JSON depicts the scenario, for service type `RUNNING REPAIR`, another collection has been created which groups all the properties related to `RUNNING REPAIR`

```
{
  "service_records": [
    {
      "service_type": "RUNNING REPAIR",
       totalAmt:2800"
      "history": [
        {
          "service_date": "08-07-22 23:17",
          "mileage": "23465",
          "jc_number": "JC22212345",
          "labour_amount": "600",
          "part_amount": "800",
          "total_amount": "1400",
        
        },
        {
          "service_date": "08-07-22 23:17",
          "mileage": "23465",
          "jc_number": "JC22212398",
          "labour_amount": "600",
          "part_amount": "800",
          "total_amount": "1400",
        
        }
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "service_type": "BODY REPAIR",
      "total_amount": "1400",
      "history": [
        {
          "service_date": "08-07-22 23:17",
          "mileage": "23465",
          "jc_number": "JC22212345",
          "labour_amount": "600",
          "part_amount": "800",
          "total_amount": "1400",
        }
      ],
       "WORKSHOP":{ //exclude body repair all other services will be count in workshop
         totalSumOfAllServices: 4774 //(running repair)
        }
    }
]
 
}
```

I did some workaround in dataweave playground but unable to group the fields according to the `serviceType`

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
service_records: payload.data map (item, index) -> {
      service_type: item.serviceType,
      labour_amount: item.labourAmt,
      part_amount: item.partAmt,
      total_amount: item.totalAmt,
      is_expanded: false,
history:payload.data map(item,v)->{
          "service_date": "08-07-22 23:17",
          "service_type": item.serviceType,
          "model": item.model,
          "mileage": item.mileage,
          "jc_number": item.jobCardNumber,
          "labour_amount": item.labourAmt,
          "part_amount": item.partAmt,
          "total_amount": item.totalAmt
} 
}
```

https://developer.mulesoft.com/learn/dataweave/playground?projectMethod=GHRepo&repo=mulesoft%2Fdocs-dataweave&path=modules%2FROOT%2Fpages%2F_partials%2Fcookbook-dw%2Fmap-ex1

Comment: From where is the `model` coming as `Alto` in the output?

Comment: you can simply ignored that one, I will edit the same, actually the response is huge, that's why I have shorten it in order to make it simple to post over here

Comment: Same for mileage and service_type, they are not mentioned in the input payload

Comment: yeah correct, there are numerous filed over there but the original json format is same, it require to group using service type and create array in case of multiple object as depicted in expected JSON outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`groupBy`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-groupby) function is what you need.
You can use it to group by the `serviceType` of the input and it will give you output which will look something like this:

```
{
  "RUNNING REPAIR": [
    {"jobCardNumber": "JC20026333", .....},
    {"jobCardNumber": "JC20026456", .....},
  ],
  "BODY REPAIR": [
    {"jobCardNumber": "JC20026456",....}
  ]
}
```

The above is the result of `payload.data groupBy $.serviceType` Which you can `pluck` and map to desired output

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
---
{
  service_records: payload.data groupBy $.serviceType 
      pluck ((groupedValues, serviceType, index) -> {
            service_type: serviceType,
            model: groupedValues[0].variant, // mabe?
            totalAmt: sum(groupedValues.totalAmt),
            history: groupedValues map {
                  service_date: "", // not sure from where it is coming from it is not in the input that you shared
                  mileage: "", // not sure from where it is coming from it is not in the input that you shared
                  jc_number: $.jobCardNumber,
                  labour_amount: $.labourAmt,
                  part_amount: $.partAmt,
                  total_amount: $.totalAmt
            }
      })
}
```

Comment: Buddy you nailed it, it works like a charm, just curious to know the significance of $ over there, you used it for every field, actually I am novice in mule, don't have much exposure

Comment: The dollar sign is the shortcut syntax or shorthand notation that can be used with lambdas. Basically `$` assumes the first parameter of the lambda, and `$$` becomes the second one. So the `groupBy`  statement can be expanded as `payload.data groupBy ((item, index) -> item.serviceType)` which will be same as `payload.data groupBy $.item`

Comment: Similarly `map` can be expanded as `history: groupedValues map ((groupedValueItem, index) -> {` then you will use `groupedValueItem` instead of `$`, so `jc_number: $.jobCardNumber,` will become `jc_number: groupedValueItem.jobCardNumber,` and so on

Comment: I need to add one more key i,e WORKSHOP, the logic would be, except BODY REPAIR service type, all other service type will clubbed into one and called WORKSHOP and also each of the service type's amount will be sum to calculate grand total. please see my edits